# SQL Server XML (multi-namespace) Parsing question

Tags: sql-server, xml, web-services, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to use SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) to parse an XML file and map the elements to database columns across several tables in a single database.

However, when I use the Data Flow Task->XML Source to try and parse an example XML file (that file is located [here](http://www.exchangenetwork.net/schema/TRI/4/TRI_ExampleInstanceDocument_v4.0.xml), XSD is located [here](http://www.exchangenetwork.net/schema/TRI/4/TRI_v4.0.zip)), it says

```
"http://www.exchangenetwork.net/schema/TRI/4:TransferWasteQuantity" has multiple members named "http://www.exchangenetwork.net/schema/TRI/F:WasteQuantityCatastrophicMeasure"
```

Is there any way to get SSIS to parse XML data such as this?  This schema changes regularly so I'd prefer to do as little parsing code outside of the data mappings as possible.  Also if there's a better way to do this outside of SSIS (say, by using SQL Server Analysis Services) then that would work too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, due to the complexity of the XML, this is not possible with the latest iterations of SQL, at least without significant modification of the incoming XML submission and XSD, which would likely lead to data corruption, therefore it is conclusive that it is not feasible to implement.